# adding exclamation points after items on my list with javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript

i created an HTML unordered list, i'd like to add to the end of each item and exclamation point using javascript.
how can i do that, i tried to use the for loop as we do with js lists but it didn't work.
please help
HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li id="test">Lemon juice</li>
        <li id="test">Watermelon</li>
        <li id="test">pomegranet</li>
        <li id="test">apple sauce</li>
        <li id="test">juice</li>
        <li id="test">Lemon juice</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please show us the JavaScript that you tried. Also note that IDs **must** be unique

Comment: you can achieve that with css as well. JS is a must?

Comment: You can do this by using class instead of id and doing .test::after { content: "!"; } in css.

Comment: i tried this
 var li = document.getElementById('test');
 for(var i =0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i] = test[i] = '!';
 }

and js is a must

Comment: `getElementById` will return one element with that ID. As the comments suggested, use classes instead. How about [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead? Also please update your question with that information, not everybody reads all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope of being useful:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].textContent += "!";
}
```

The version by PhobosFerro is also very clean and nice, though.
And as stated in other posts before mine, you should use "class" instead of "id". IDs have to be unique.